# JavaScript Filter 3rd level nested array of object

Tags: javascript, filter

I have the json data and am trying to filter the nested array object which have in 3rd level.

Sample data:

```
   var data = {
    "cList": [
        {
            "Id": "111111",
            "Number": "176116",
            "Name": "Test",
            "gList": [
                {


                    "gNumber": "123456",
                    "productList": [
                        {
                            "spn": "2118593162",
                            "pno": "2118593163",
                            "effectiveDate": "12/12/2023",
                            "partB": false,
                            "id": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "spn": "2131493390",
                            "pno": "2131493390",
                            "effectiveDate": "01/01/2020",
                            "partB": false,
                            "id": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "spn": "2100171794",
                            "pno": "2100171794",
                            "benefitPlanType": "Wellness Programs",
                            "effectiveDate": "01/01/2023",
                            "partB": false,
                            "id": ""
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "gNumber": "10422798",
                    "productList": [
                        {
                            "spn": "2118593162",
                            "pno": "2118593163",
                            "effectiveDate": "01/01/2022",
                            "partB": false,
                            "id": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "spn": "2131493390",
                            "pno": "2131493390",
                            "effectiveDate": "01/01/2020",
                            "partB": false,
                            "id": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "spn": "2100171794",
                            "pno": "2100171794",
                            "benefitPlanType": "Wellness Programs",
                            "effectiveDate": "01/01/2023",
                            "partB": false,
                            "id": ""
                        }
                    ],
                },
                {
                    "gNumber": "10422700",
                    "productList": [
                        {
                            "spn": "2118593162",
                            "pno": "2118593163",
                            "effectiveDate": "01/01/2023",
                            "partB": false,
                            "id": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "spn": "2131493390",
                            "pno": "2131493390",
                            "effectiveDate": "01/01/2020",
                            "partB": false,
                            "id": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "spn": "2100171794",
                            "pno": "2100171794",
                            "benefitPlanType": "Wellness Programs",
                            "effectiveDate": "01/01/2023"
                        },
                    ],
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": "222",
            "Number": "176116",
            "Name": "Test",
            "gList": [
                {
                    "gNumber": "1234567",
                    "productList": [
                        {
                            "spn": "2118593162",
                            "pno": "2118593163",
                            "effectiveDate": "12/12/2010",
                            "partB": false,
                            "id": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "spn": "2131493390",
                            "pno": "2131493390",
                            "effectiveDate": "01/01/2020",
                            "partB": false,
                            "id": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "spn": "2100171794",
                            "pno": "2100171794",
                            "benefitPlanType": "Wellness Programs",
                            "effectiveDate": "01/01/2023",
                            "partB": false,
                            "id": ""
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "gNumber": "10422798",
                    "productList": [
                        {
                            "spn": "2118593162",
                            "pno": "2118593163",
                            "effectiveDate": "01/01/2022",
                            "partB": false,
                            "id": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "spn": "2131493390",
                            "pno": "2131493390",
                            "effectiveDate": "01/01/2020",
                            "partB": false,
                            "id": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "spn": "2100171794",
                            "pno": "2100171794",
                            "benefitPlanType": "Wellness Programs",
                            "effectiveDate": "01/01/2023",
                            "partB": false,
                            "id": ""
                        }
                    ],
                },
                {
                    "gNumber": "10422795",
                    "productList": [
                        {
                            "spn": "2118593162",
                            "pno": "2118593163",
                            "effectiveDate": "12/12/2023",
                            "partB": false,
                            "id": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "spn": "2131493390",
                            "pno": "2131493390",
                            "effectiveDate": "01/01/2020",
                            "partB": false,
                            "id": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "spn": "2100171794",
                            "pno": "2100171794",
                            "benefitPlanType": "Wellness Programs",
                            "effectiveDate": "01/01/2023"
                        },
                    ],
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
};
```

I am trying to get the gNumber's only which have in the productList array  effectiveDate = "12/12/2023";

or

Get the first matched result also fine.

```
const filteredClientList = data.cList.filter(
    (cListElement) =>
        cListElement.gList.find(
            (gListElement) =>
                gListElement.productList.filter((productListElement) => productListElement.effectiveDate === "12/12/2023"),
        ),
);
console.log("filteredClientList", JSON.stringify(filteredClientList));
```

Expected output:

```
[
  {
    "gNumber": "123456",
    "productList": [
      {
        "spn": "2118593162",
        "pno": "2118593163",
        "effectiveDate": "12/12/2023",
        "partB": false,
        "id": ""
      },
      {
        "spn": "2131493390",
        "pno": "2131493390",
        "effectiveDate": "01/01/2020",
        "partB": false,
        "id": ""
      },
      {
        "spn": "2100171794",
        "pno": "2100171794",
        "benefitPlanType": "Wellness Programs",
        "effectiveDate": "01/01/2023",
        "partB": false,
        "id": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "gNumber": "10422795",
    "productList": [
      {
        "spn": "2118593162",
        "pno": "2118593163",
        "effectiveDate": "12/12/2023",
        "partB": false,
        "id": ""
      },
      {
        "spn": "2131493390",
        "pno": "2131493390",
        "effectiveDate": "01/01/2020",
        "partB": false,
        "id": ""
      },
      {
        "spn": "2100171794",
        "pno": "2100171794",
        "benefitPlanType": "Wellness Programs",
        "effectiveDate": "01/01/2023"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: The result of filter is an array (empty or otherwise) which is always truthy.  Instead of the innermost filter you could try `.some`

Comment: The result may be empty as well.. because the data is getting form thirdparty.

Comment: @James - Either get the list of matched gNumber or get the first matched result also fine.

Comment: Don't just add more details in comments, though. Update your post. However, that doesn't change the code solution: if the data has no matching entries, then you expect an empty array from `filter`.

Comment: Yes @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) followed by a [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with a [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) inside.
`flatMap` is equivalent to doing a `map` followed by a `flat()`.
`flatMap` gets you the all data in a`[{gNumber,productList},...]`. Now to filter it the condition must be at least one of `productList` should have the given `effectiveDate`. For that `some` is used

```js
var data = { "cList": [ { "Id": "111111", "Number": "176116", "Name": "Test", "gList": [ {                "gNumber": "123456",                "productList": [                    {                        "spn": "2118593162",                        "pno": "2118593163",                        "effectiveDate": "12/12/2023",                        "partB": false,                        "id": ""                    },                    {                        "spn": "2131493390",                        "pno": "2131493390",                        "effectiveDate": "01/01/2020",                        "partB": false,                        "id": ""                    },                    {                        "spn": "2100171794",                        "pno": "2100171794",                        "benefitPlanType": "Wellness Programs",                       "effectiveDate": "01/01/2023",                        "partB": false,                        "id": ""                    }                ]            },            {                "gNumber": "10422798",                "productList": [                    {                        "spn": "2118593162",                        "pno": "2118593163",                        "effectiveDate": "01/01/2022",                        "partB": false,                        "id": ""                    },                    {                        "spn": "2131493390",                        "pno": "2131493390",                        "effectiveDate": "01/01/2020",                        "partB": false,                        "id": ""                    },                    {                        "spn": "2100171794",                        "pno": "2100171794",                        "benefitPlanType": "Wellness Programs",                        "effectiveDate": "01/01/2023",                        "partB": false,                        "id": ""                    }                ],            },            {                "gNumber": "10422700","productList": [                    {                        "spn": "2118593162",                        "pno": "2118593163",                        "effectiveDate": "01/01/2023",                        "partB": false,                        "id": ""                    },                    {                        "spn": "2131493390",                        "pno": "2131493390",                        "effectiveDate": "01/01/2020",                        "partB": false,                        "id": ""                    },                    {                        "spn": "2100171794",                        "pno": "2100171794",                        "benefitPlanType": "Wellness Programs",                        "effectiveDate": "01/01/2023"                    },                ],            }        ]    },    {        "Id": "222",        "Number": "176116",        "Name": "Test",        "gList": [            {                "gNumber": "1234567",                "productList": [                    {                        "spn": "2118593162",                        "pno": "2118593163",                        "effectiveDate": "12/12/2010",                        "partB": false,                        "id": ""                    },                    {                        "spn": "2131493390",                        "pno": "2131493390",                        "effectiveDate": "01/01/2020",                        "partB": false,                        "id": ""                    },                    {                        "spn": "2100171794",                        "pno": "2100171794",                        "benefitPlanType": "Wellness Programs",                        "effectiveDate": "01/01/2023",                        "partB": false,                        "id": ""                    }                ]            },            {                "gNumber": "10422798",                "productList": [                    {                        "spn": "2118593162",                        "pno": "2118593163",                        "effectiveDate": "01/01/2022",                        "partB": false,                        "id": ""                    },                    {                        "spn": "2131493390",                        "pno": "2131493390",                        "effectiveDate": "01/01/2020",                        "partB": false,                        "id": ""                    },                    {                        "spn": "2100171794",                        "pno": "2100171794",                        "benefitPlanType": "Wellness Programs",                        "effectiveDate": "01/01/2023",                        "partB": false,                        "id": ""                    }                ],            },            {                "gNumber": "10422795",                "productList": [                    {                        "spn": "2118593162",                        "pno": "2118593163",                        "effectiveDate": "12/12/2023",                        "partB": false,                        "id": ""                    },                    {                        "spn": "2131493390",                        "pno": "2131493390",                        "effectiveDate": "01/01/2020",                        "partB": false,                        "id": ""                    },                    {                        "spn": "2100171794",                        "pno": "2100171794",                        "benefitPlanType": "Wellness Programs",                        "effectiveDate": "01/01/2023"                    },                ],            }        ]    }],}

const filtered = data.cList.flatMap(x => x.gList).filter(y => y.productList.some(z => z.effectiveDate === '12/12/2023') )

console.log(filtered)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```